# How to get X and Y values when click on item in gridView

Tags: android, gridview

I want to get the X and Y values for an item of grid view when I click on it, but how do I do this or how do I get these values?

I know I'll use the setOnItemClickListener method, but I can only get the position from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I get x and y coordinates of where the user clicks on Google Maps. Try if replacing it with other kinds of views works with you

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m) {
if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    long start = e.getEventTime();
    x = (int)e.getX();
    y = (int)e.getY();
    touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);
}
```

Here map is name of my MapView . Basically it fetched X, Y from MotionEvent

Comment: this is works for me thanks ..and i have another question ..i want to get the count of the images in the row or or in the column like in the game connect Four ..do u have any idea how to get it

Answer (score 0):

Set a touch listener by calling

```
grid.setOnTouchListener().
```

One of the parameters is a `MotionEvent` object, which would include the x and y positions.